# Are there languages which restrict adverb usage to only one of either preceding or following a verb?

Tags: syntax, morphosyntax, adverbs

We have adverb sentences like this:

> I basically initially ran quickly.

That means the same thing *pretty much* as:

> I basically initially quickly ran.

First part of the question is, why do some precede and some follow the verb in English? But main part of the question is, are there any languages which **restrict** how adverbs are placed in a sentence, much more than this? By that I mean, maybe they are only allowed to be sequentially placed *before* a verb, or only sequentially placed after a verb, but not both. If so, what are 1 or 2 languages which have a more restricted adverb syntax?

Comment: Without checking anything, my immediate guess would be that most languages probably allow only one or the other as a general rule. Assuming, that is, that you’re not including adverbs preceding the whole subject–verb entity, which I think are fairly universal (as in “_Yesterday_ I basically ran quickly”).